# css class doesn't work properly for text area

Tags: html, css

I have a form in which there are three text boxes and a text area. i customized the appearance of all these elements in the form using css classes. but the text inside the text area was not formated like the text boxes. why is this happening only to the text area, while text boxes are working fine. Here's a picture of the problem.[image]

And here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact_form">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input id="Text1" class="text" type="text" placeholder="Name:" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <input id="Text2" class="text" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail:" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <input id="Text3" class="text" type="text" placeholder="Phone:" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <textarea id="TextArea1" class="text textarea" placeholder="Message"></textarea></li>
                </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 #contact_form ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

.text {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: red;
    background: brown;
    padding: 2%;
    margin:0 0 10px 8%;
}
.textarea {
    resize:vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add font properties to your css: for default are different

```
.text {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: red;
  background: brown;
  padding: 2%;
  margin:0 0 10px 8%;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:11px;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/4dW37/1/**

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, misread your question. But if you wanted to change the color of the placeholder text, you now know lol.**

You need to style the placeholder pseudo-elements directly...

Note, you can't combine them all into one function. Each Pseudo-element needs to be styled separately.

Example:

```
input.text::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
}

input.text:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: white;  
}

input.text::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: white;  
}

input.text:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: white;  
}
```

Comment: then why is this not required for text-boxes. why is it working properly, without these codes, for text boxes?

Comment: No idea...re: textboxes. Might be a browser by browser experience. Use the above as a fail safe. Remove the `input` so it's just `.text:` etc. so it works across the board.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a font-family attribute to text class.

```
.text {font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;}
```